Normalization in pandas via function
I have this dataframe:
    age
0   48
1   7
2   62
3   48
4   51

This code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def normalizar(x):
  # Convert x to a numpy array to allow for vectorized operations.
  x = np.array(x)
  # Calculate the minimum and maximum values of x.
  xmin = x.min()
  xmax = x.max()
  # Normalize the array x using vectorized operations.
  return (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)

df["age_n"] = df["age"].apply(normalizar)
df

and I get:
   age  age_n
0   48    NaN
1    7    NaN
2   62    NaN
3   48    NaN
4   51    NaN

How can I solve this issue?
The expected result would be values between [0,1]

What result should you get, maybe also include that?

@mrconcerned done

This question is similar to: Normalize columns of a dataframe. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Series.apply invokes a function on the individual values of the series. What you are looking for is: df['age_n'] = normalizar(df['age']). (and you don't need x = np.array(x).)

You have created a vectorized function for the normalization.  This function takes the entire column of data.  .apply pass in one element at a time to the function.

@James Thank you, that is why, I finally get it

How would it be with .apply?

@Another.Chemist With .apply()? Hmm, maybe you meant something like df.apply(normalizar)? That would apply the function to each column. Of course, there's only one here, but if you had more columns and you wanted to normalize all of them, you could use that.

@Another.Chemist it would be pointless to do it with .apply() as you would need to normalize all columns.

In the future, please start with your own debugging. For example, if you just checked what x is, you would find the problem yourself. For tips, see How to debug small programs by Eric Lippert and How to step through Python code to help debug issues?

The problem appears with your .apply() function which actually not needed as your function handles it. You just need to feed the whole column to it:
df["age_n"] = normalizar(df["age"])

OP asked how it could be done with .apply() where you need to normalize all your columns (which of course is not really good approach), but in case sharing answer for it too.
def normalizar(x, xmin, xmax):
    return (x - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)

# and find min/max values 
xmin = df['age'].min()
xmax = df['age'].max()

# and apply normalization 
df["age_n"] = df["age"].apply(lambda x: normalizar(x, xmin, xmax))


"normalize all your [columns]" - That's not what that code does.
